# JPA MEMBER OF Query with detached Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I want to do a simple JPA MEMBER OF query but I cannot for the life of mine get it to work. Hibernate throws an TransientObjectException with the message "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the instance before flushing: Tag". The query is as follows:

```
public Collection<ItemDescription> getItems(){
    String entityClass = "ItemDescription";
    TypedQuery<ItemDescription> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT i FROM " + entityClass +" i " +
            "WHERE :tag MEMBER OF i.tags", ItemDescription.class);
    query.setParameter("tag", new Tag("category:test"));
    List<ItemDescription> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

The two entity classes look as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag extends AbstractDomainEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2632379096725992272L;
    private String value;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "itemdescriptions")
public class ItemDescription extends AbstractDomainEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9164310940207023539L;
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    private void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

The same query works when I use a Tag object retrieved from the entity manager as the query parameter. Does the "tag" parameter really have to be a managed entity? Why? How can I get the query to work? Thank you guys for your help!

[EDIT:]
Thank you for your hints. I now ended up with this query:

```
public Collection<ItemDescription> getItems(){
    String entityClass = "ItemDescription";
    TypedQuery<ItemDescription> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT i FROM " + entityClass +" i " +
            "JOIN i.tags t " +
            "WHERE t.value = :tag", ItemDescription.class);
    query.setParameter("tag", "category:test");
    List<ItemDescription> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nayan Wadekar stated, the `:memberParameter MEMBER OF i.tags` requires a persistent instance.

So there are two solution approaches here.

1. Ensure that you pass in a already persistent instance of a Tag-object.
2. If you cannot do that, you can query by the 'tag'-name via a JOIN-query:

   ```
   SELECT i FROM ItemDescription i JOIN c.tags t
   WHERE t.name LIKE :name
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When the transaction commits, all the objects in the persistence context are being synchronized with the underlying database. Therefore, when you are setting the object retrieved by entity manager works fine, as object is in managed state.

Here, you are creating a new object & setting it as a parameter for a query in a transaction, results in exception as object is detached.

**From Documentation :**

> Thrown when the user passes a transient instance to a Session method
>   that expects a persistent instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought this is supported as I have seen such an example here [Persistence Pays Offs: Advanced Mapping with JPA](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/33906/1763/page/2) So I guess his example wouldn't work either.